# How to cache phone contacts in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am starting to learn flutter and was creating a contact management application.

I am using the 'contacts_service' package to get phone contacts on app load.

This return a

```
Future<Iterable<Contact>>
```

where Contact is defined in contacts_service.dart.

Contact has a toMap and fromMap function.

Calling the ContactsService.getContacts(); on every app load causes the app to load slowly. I was wondering what is to best way to cache this data. Cache manager packages are all aimed at http calls (atleast I couldn't find one for this). I tried to write manually to the temp folder. I am stuck at how to store the List in the file. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I want to cache the data across app launches. So what i want to know is how should I store this data?

Comment: with [json](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json) for example?

Answer (score 1):

You can use database [sqflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite).

Or use key-value database [hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive) for which is fast.

```dart
var contactBox = await Hive.openBox("contact");
await contactBox.addAll(contacts);
``
```